# Matrix Algebra calculation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am new to linear algebra. If my answer is wrong could you give me some tips. Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Q: If A^2 − 2A + I = 0, show A^3 = 3A − 2I

What I did:

A^2  = 2A - I
A(A^2)  = A(2A - I)
A^3  = 3A - AI

I get stuck here... doesn't AI = I? I feel like I am missing a rule.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In your 3rd step you turn A(2A-I) into 3A - AI; that is not valid, even given that A^2 = 2A+I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assumption, $A^2=2A-I$, which implies
$$A^3=A(A^2)=A(2A-I)=2A^2-A=2(2A-I)-A=3A-2I.$$

Comment: thanks for the info paul! I have a question though I don't understand this process that you did:  2A^2−A=2(2A−I)−A   could you explain it plz?

Comment: I just substitute $2A-I$ for $A^2$, since $A^2=2A-I$ by assumption.

Comment: ohh haha silly me. Thank you! I appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 0):

$$
A^3 -3A + 2I = (A-I) (A^2 + A - 2I) = (A-I)(A-I) (A+2I) = (A^2-2A+I)(A-2I)=0
$$
So $A^3 = 3A -2I$.